# Partial Derivative in Linear Model, how are they calculated?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning

Here is a flowchart I am struggling with:
[image]

I am a programmer with a weak math background. I don't understand for example how the partial derivative of $\hat{y}$ in respect to weight 1 equals $= x_1$.

I understand the importance of them, however I cannot see how to calculate them.I have been on Khan Academy and nothing is clicking any assistance would be much appreciated!

Here is the [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/step-by-step-tutorial-on-linear-regression-with-stochastic-gradient-descent-1d35b088a843#e0d5) that uses the chart for further context.

Comment: So you want just the partial derivative of $\hat{y}$ with respect to $x_1$ ? We know the expression for $\hat{y}$:
$$
\hat{y} = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + b 
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{ \partial x_1} = w_1
$$
That's the normal derivative of the expression, with respect to $x_1$. Nothing difficult here ...

Comment: If you need more steps to this, you could see the differentiation procedure as:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \left( w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 +b \right) 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \left[ w_1 x_1 \right] +  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}  \left[w_2 x_2 \right]  + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}  \left[ b \right] \\
&= w_1 + 0 + 0 \\
& = w_1
\end{split}
$$
Is it clearer now?

Comment: That is what I needed! Thanks @MattiP.

Comment: All of the resources I have been using all had inputs in the function, so was confused.